# replace value in column of dataframe with suitable values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I want to replace Value Nan in F1[id1] with 0 . Else `F1[id1] = 1`

code:
it doesn't work. How can i solve it please
`F1.id1 = [0 if pd.isna(e) else 1 for e in F1.id1]`
[Here the output ofF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDzJH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use fillna():

```
F1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: but like this i will replace all Nans in DAtaframe not only in F1['id1']